# How to loop over folders of a directory?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I am in the directory a1 and there is another directory submissions in a1. without using cd to submissions, how can I print of the folder names in submissions while staying in a1? Can I do the following? I am shell-scripting.

for dir in */submissions; do
...
done

Answer (score 1):

Using a bourne or Posix shell, you can do:

```
for dir in ./submission/*
do
    if test -d $dir
    then ...
    fi
done
```

Comment: so it wont work for bash? because when I do this and type echo $dir, all I get is ./submission/*

Comment: `bash` is mainly compatible with bourne and Posix so it should work... if you really have folders under submission.

Comment: yeah, I have folders under submission but when I do this, it just echoes the pathname I wrote in the for loop, not the file names.

Comment: @badcaptain : You asked in your question to _print the folder names in submissions_. In the answer given by SergeBallesta, the variable `dir` contains such a folder name, so you can just print it, using (for instance) `echo $dir`, or do whatever else you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this is the folder structure you have:

```
/a1/submissions/file1
/a1/submissions/file2
/a1/submissions/file3
```

You can use the `ls [OPTIONS] [FILES]` command to get a list of files and or directories:

If you provide `ls` with an absolute path (meaning starting from the "root" level) you can list the contents of that path regardless of where you currently are (provided you have the access rights).

So to get a list of all files in the submissions subfolder, you can run `ls /a1/submissions`  which will output something like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: i am shell-scripting so no use of ls right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that using recursions.

```
#!/bin/sh

func () { # $1=directory
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            func "$file" # Enter another recursion if "$file" is a folder.
        else
            echo "$file" # Print filename
        fi
    done
}

cd a1
func '.'
# Or this for absolute paths
# func "$(realpath .)"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler then to use `find`?

Comment: @user1934428 - Sure you can. `find`, `ls` or any other programs for that matter. It just one way to achieve the same thing.